# how can i create a flick "momemtum effect" on an object like IOS picker view using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

http://codepen.io/PageOnline/pen/Lkdue

the link above is to a "safe" type combo lock
when you click on one of the numbers it moves to the next. (as expected).
I am trying to re-create this but instead use a "flick" motion to be able to spin it using ccs 3 rotate z. the problem is i cannot find any examples or "stack" questions that address momentum and inertia that don't involve canvas. is there any other way to be able to "flick" the numbers so they spin and slow down and eventually stop? kind of like IOS pickers?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the keyframes for the speeding up and slowing down part. That's the most I can do for you.
http://jsfiddle.net/p8GWT/

```
    #logo:hover{
  -webkit-animation-name: rotateThis;
  -webkit-animation-duration:2s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function:ease-in-out;

  -moz-animation-name: rotateThis;
  -moz-animation-duration:2s;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -moz-animation-timing-function:ease-in-out;

  -ms-animation-name: rotateThis;
  -ms-animation-duration:2s;
  -ms-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -ms-animation-timing-function:ease-in-out;

  animation-name: rotateThis;
  animation-duration:2s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-timing-function:ease-in-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotateThis {
    0% { -webkit-transform:scale(1) rotate(0deg); }
    10% { -webkit-transform:scale(1.1) rotate(0deg); }
    90% {-webkit-transform:scale(1.1) rotate(360deg);}
    100% { -webkit-transform:scale(1) rotate(360deg); }
}
@-moz-keyframes rotateThis {
    0% { -moz-transform:scale(1) rotate(0deg); }
    10% { -moz-transform:scale(1.1) rotate(0deg); }
    90% {-moz-transform:scale(1.1) rotate(360deg);}
    100% { -moz-transform:scale(1) rotate(360deg); }
}
@-ms-keyframes rotateThis {
    0% { -ms-transform:scale(1) rotate(0deg); }
    10% { -ms-transform:scale(1.1) rotate(0deg); }
    90% {-ms-transform:scale(1.1) rotate(360deg);}
    100% { -ms-transform:scale(1) rotate(360deg); }
}
@keyframes rotateThis {
    0% { transform:scale(1) rotate(0deg); }
    10% { transform:scale(1.1) rotate(0deg); }
    90% { transform:scale(1.1) rotate(360deg);}
    100% { transform:scale(1) rotate(360deg); }
}
```

Comment: yes but that does not handle momentum. I know i have to use a cubic bezier curve with keytframes